# Python Countdown Timer includes Extra Zero

Tags: python, timer, clock

I'm attempting to make a timer that, once inputing any amount of minutes, the window will count down the time in a mm:ss format. however, when inputing a time over 10 mins, when the minutes get below 10 after starting at any time above 10 minutes, an extra zero appears at the end of the timer. I cannot seem to figure out how to get rid of it and was hoping for another set of eyes to see if I've made any silly mistakes.

```
import time, sys, os
os.system("cls")
def countdown_screen(endtime):
    sectot=int(endtime)*60
    print("*******************************************************************************")
    for i in range(0,sectot):
        mins=(int(sectot)/60)
        secs=sectot-(mins*60)
        if secs<10:
            secs="0"+str(secs)
        if mins==10 and secs==0:
            secs=secs-"0"
        sys.stdout.write("\rSystem standby for: %s:%s" %(mins,secs))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        sectot=sectot-1     
    sys.stdout.write("\rSystem standby complete.")
    print""
endtime=raw_input("mins:")
countdown_screen(endtime)
```

Comment: Just a small hack, add a space: `sys.stdout.write("\rSystem standby for: %s:%s " %(mins,secs))`

Comment: hey @user38024 This does indeed work thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are overloading `secs` to be an int and then a string, that's sure to be a problem:

```
    if secs<10:
        secs="0"+str(secs)
    if mins==10 and secs==0:
        secs=secs-"0"
```

But you should simplify your whole approach and let string formatting do the work for you:

```
import time, sys, os
os.system("cls")
def countdown_screen(endtime):
    sectot=int(endtime)*60
    print("*******************************************************************************")
    for i in range(0,sectot):
        sys.stdout.write("\rSystem standby for: %02d:%02d" % (sectot/60,sectot%60))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        sectot=sectot-1     
    sys.stdout.write("\rSystem standby complete.")
    print""
endtime=raw_input("mins:")
countdown_screen(endtime)
```

Comment: ahh okay that gets rid of the extra one at the end, but now i have an extra one at the beginning.

Comment: When I run it, there isn't anything weird unless I go over 99 minutes and the "extra spaces at the end" trick should work.

Comment: Oh wait, you can fix that w/ spaces at the end of `sys.stdout.write("\rSystem standby complete.")`.